# How can I make my Sublime Text2 back to default setting?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I am a new guy into coding world, and I am now using Sublime Text2 on Mac, but there is such a weird problem here. When I am writing CSS & HTML codes:

[image]
[image]

Obviously, you can see, I don't want this "margin直接写是top" thing, I don't even know where it comes from. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not detecting an already present string in your source code, I guess this comes from an installed package. If you're using [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/about), open the command palette and type List Packages. Otherwise to go your Sublime Text [user folder](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/basic_concepts.html) and have a look.

Comment: I went to user folder, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Take a look at the installed packages. I don't remember the exact location in Sublime Text 2 (I'm using ST3), but I think they're in the "Packages" directory. However, the quickest way to detect the package responsible for the completion is probably by loading the entire user folder into Sublime Text and search all files for the string `margin直接写是top`. If you have Package Control installed, you can then disable or remove the package. Otherwise, you can delete the package (or just the responsible file) from the user folder.